# JS Intellisense not working for EXTERNAL URL files in VS2012

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Are external JS files not supported in intellisense for vs 2012 ?

WORKS

```
<reference path="Model.js"/>
```

Does NOT work

```
<reference path="http://localhost/MyProject/Model.js"/>
```

Model.js is auto created via a http module, any idea how I get this to work ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, they do work. Are you sure that http://localhost/MyProject works all the time (i.e. are you setup under IIS or does the project only run in Express from VS)? Even if it does, why are you using that and not a relative path?

Comment: It was originally setup with express but as I suspected this might be the problem I changed it to IIS and same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running my code through JSLint and fixing all the issues it shows now up correctly. Intellisense should popup a warning if the parser cannot process the code.

Comment: Agreed there...There's not nearly enough visibility to the intellisense JS parser... at least not as far as I'm aware